# ¿Como se puede actualizar datos de una tabla que se construye dinamicamente con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Les platico sobre mi problema, tengo una tabla que se construye con datos que trae el back, entonces al insertar un boton de editar, este solo quiero que edite 2 posiciones de la tabla que son:
Cantidad
Precio unitario
El cual si cambia algun dato de estos, se multiplican para poder poner el importe de un articulo,
entonces cuando cambia este dato que es el de importe debe de sumar el importe de todos los articulos que estan en la tabla.
Pero cuando se realiza este cambio que es llamado por un popup la suma no la hace, les agradeceria si pudieran brindar una solución tengo la idea pero ya trate con varias opciones y no me sale, les dejo como es que tengo mi codigo, con datos fijos simulando lo que tengo.
Muchas gracias.
Les dejo tambien unas fotos de como se ejecuta.
[la tabla dinamica donde esta el boton de editar y aparece el popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogMyw.png)
[image: el popup donde escribes los cambios a ese producto]
[image: aqui se actualizan los datos y el importe pero no hace la suma del total]

```js
<script>
    //FUNCION DATOS TABLA POPUP==========================================================================
function abrirPopupActualizarProductos(cantidadEditar, precioUnitarioEditar, idDetalleEditar, num, columna2, columna3, columna4){
    var cantidad   = cantidadEditar;
    var importe   = precioUnitarioEditar;
    detalleId = idDetalleEditar;
    fila = num;
    col2 = columna2;
    col3 = columna3;
    col4 = columna4;

    $("#cantidadEditar").val(cantidad);
    $("#precioUnitarioEditar").val(importe);

    $("#popupEditarProductosTabla").modal("toggle");
}
//====================================================================================================

//FUNCION ACTUALIZAR DATOS TABLA==========================================================================
function actualizarProductos(){
    var cantidad = $("#cantidadEditar").val();
    var importe  = $("#precioUnitarioEditar").val();

    var total = cantidad * importe;

    if ((fila >= 1) && (col2 == 2) && (col3 == 3) && (col4 == 4)) {
    var celdas = document.getElementById('tablaProductosAnadidosEditar').rows[fila].cells;

    celdas[col2].innerHTML = cantidad;
    celdas[col3].innerHTML = importe;
    celdas[col4].innerHTML = total;
  }
}
//====================================================================================================

//EVENTO READY========================================================================================
$(document).ready(function(){
    sumaEditar = new Array();
    productosTabla = new Array();
    moneda = "TOTAL $";
});
//====================================================================================================

function obtener_datos_cotizaciones_editar(){
    var idDetalleEditar              ="213"
    var cantidadEditar               ="2";
    var claveEditar                  ="10101508";
    var descripcionEditar            ="Comida para cerdos";
    var importeEditar                ="400";
    var precioUnitarioEditar         ="200";

    var productosTabla = new Array();
    var tabla = document.querySelectorAll("#tablaProductosAnadidosEditar tbody tr");
    var ref = tabla.length + 1;
    var num = ref;
    var columna2 = 2;
    var columna3 = 3;
    var columna4 = 4;

    var htmlProdCotizEditar =
    "<tr fila='"+num+"'>"+
        "<td class='clavesProductos'>"+claveEditar+"</td>"+
        "<td class='desProductos'>"+descripcionEditar+"</td>"+
        "<td class='cantProductos' columna='"+columna2+"'>"+cantidadEditar+"</td>"+
        "<td class='precioProductos' columna='"+columna3+"'>"+precioUnitarioEditar+"</td>"+
        "<td class='totalImporteProductos' columna='"+columna4+"'>"+importeEditar+"</td>"+
        "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-danger botonEliminar' onclick='eliminarProductoEditar()' style='width: 50%;'><img src='../iconos/eliminar.png' style='width: 20px;'></button><br><button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-warning botonEditarProducto' onclick='abrirPopupActualizarProductos("+cantidadEditar+", "+precioUnitarioEditar+", "+idDetalleEditar+", "+num+", "+columna2+", "+columna3+", "+columna4+");' style='width: 50%;'><img src='../iconos/editar.png' style='width: 20px;'></td>"+
        "<td class='idProductos' style='visibility:collapse; display:none;'>"+idDetalleEditar+"</td>"+
    "</tr>";
    $(".prodCotizEditar").append(htmlProdCotizEditar);

    var trs=document.querySelectorAll("#tablaProductosAnadidosEditar tbody tr").forEach(function(e){
        produAgreNvo = {
            descripcion: e.querySelector('.desProductos').innerText,
            precioUnitario: e.querySelector('.precioProductos').innerText,
            cantidad: e.querySelector('.cantProductos').innerText,
            idProducto: e.querySelector('.idProductos').innerText
        };
    });
    productosTabla.push(produAgreNvo);

    var total = 0;

    $('.totalProductosEditar').each(function(){

        if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
          total += Number($(this).val());
          $(".totalCantidadProductosEditar").text(moneda+total.toLocaleString('es-MX'));
          $(".cantidadTotalEditar").val(total);
        }else{alert("si es nan");}
    });
    console.log(productosTabla);
}
//EVENTO READY========================================================================================
$(document).ready(function(){
    obtener_datos_cotizaciones_editar();
});
//===================================================================================================
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">EDITAR COTIZACIÓN</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-primary tablaProductosTotalEditar" id="tablaProductosAnadidosEditar">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Clave</th>
                        <th>Descripción</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Precio Unitario</th>
                        <th>Importe</th>
                        <th>Operación</th>
                        <th style="visibility:collapse; display:none;"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="prodCotizEditar">
                    <tr>
                        <td class='clavesProductos'>1545621</td>
                        <td class='desProductos'>Comida para perros</td>
                        <td class='cantProductos'>2</td>
                        <td class='precioProductos'>500</td>
                        <td class='totalImporteProductos'>1000</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-danger botonEliminar' onclick='eliminarProductoEditar()' style='width: 50%;'><img src='../iconos/eliminar.png' style='width: 20px;'></button><br><button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-warning botonEditarProducto' onclick='abrirPopupActualizarProductos();' style='width: 50%;'><img src='../iconos/editar.png' style='width: 20px;'>
                        </td>
                        <td class='idProductos' style="visibility:collapse; display:none;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<div id="popupEditarProductosTabla" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <center><h4 class="modal-title">Editar Productos de Cotización</h4></center>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 modal-body formularioEditarProdTabla">
        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
            <p>Cantidad</p>
            <input class="input100" type="text" class="" name="cantidadEditar" id="cantidadEditar">
            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
            <p>Precio Unitario</p>
            <input class="input100" type="text" class="" name="precioUnitarioEditar" id="precioUnitarioEditar">
            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8 modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="actualizarProductos(this);">Actualizar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```